# Unable to do a Realm migration in Swift

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I have a reminder object, that I just modified. Here is the original version:

```
class Reminder: Object {
   @objc dynamic var title = ""
   @objc dynamic var parents = ""
   @objc dynamic var lists = "All"
   @objc dynamic var labels = "All"
   @objc dynamic var priority = 
   @objc dynamic var notes = ""
   @objc dynamic var reminderType = .none
}
```

and here is the new version:

```
class Reminder: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var parents = ""
    @objc dynamic var lists = "All"
    @objc dynamic var dueDate = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var reminderDate = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var reminderLocation = ""
    @objc dynamic var labels = "All"
    @objc dynamic var priority = 1
    @objc dynamic var notes = ""
}
```

I have implemented a migration block `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the AppDelegate. Here it is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    ///Realm migration
    let config = Realm.Configuration(
        // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
        // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
        schemaVersion: 2,

        // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
        // a schema version lower than the one set above
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

            if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {

            }
    }
    )
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
    let _ = try! Realm()

    return true
}
```

According to the documentation, I believe that it should be a functional migration. However, I get the following error while compiling the app:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Reminder.reminderLocation' has been added.
- Property 'Reminder.reminderDate' has been added.
- Property 'Reminder.dueDate' has been added.
- Property 'Reminder.reminderType' has been removed."
```

What should I change in my migration block?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception will be thrown when stored data doesn’t match the model you have in code.

You shouldn’t need to do anything in the migration block, however you will need to trigger a migration by updating the value of `Realm.Configuration.schemaVersion`, e.g.:

```
schemaVersion: 3,
```

Comment: I had already updated the value of the `schemaVersion`to 2 (it was previously 1) and it did not work. I just tried again and set it to 3 to no avail. Any other ideas on what may be causing it?

Comment: Strange, you may need to write the migration block to add in default values. It may also be to do with the enum in the original version as Realm doesn't specifically support enums. Have you released the app already? A quick fix while you're developing is to delete your existing app and reinstall.